# Joining regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

How to join several (javascript) regular expressions into a single one?

For example, given `[/^abcd$/,/^abxy$/,/^abz$/]` the output will be `/^ab(cd|xy|z)$/`.

Is it even computationally possible?

Comment: Joining is easy, just or (`|`) the different expressions. Your question implies that you want the tool to also "simplify" the expression. How do you measure the complexity of a regexp?

Comment: The "tool" I've used in the past is this Perl module http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Regexp-Optimizer-0.15/lib/Regexp/Optimizer.pm Just join them as the above comment says, and then run the regex through it and it will be optimized.

Comment: @crypticツ how successful was that experimental tool?  if one is skeptical of the results then I'd stay away from it unless you're just wanting to learn regex

Comment: @gillyspy: It worked great. Now I never did try it on very complex expressions, but doing what the OP is asking for would be simpler than what I passed to it. I mean it's basically doing [this](http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Regexp-Optimizer-0.15/lib/Regexp/Optimizer.pm#DESCRIPTION) which is not a very complex optimization, so the chances of something breaking would be next to none especially with something like above example from OP. Try it out! =o)

Answer (score 4):

It is quite easy to make such a tool for simple cases. Just put each pattern into parentheses and join them with "|". So for your example set of patterns it becomes:

```
/(^abcd$)|(^abxy$)|(^abz$)/
```

On a second thought, parentheses might not be necessary, so this will do:

```
/^abcd$|^abxy$|^abz$/
```

Comment: `/((?:^abcd$)|(?:^abxy$)|(?:^abz$))/` maybe this is a better solution to group it in 1 matching group ?

Comment: Provided JavaScript regexes support (?:) using them is indeed better. However, I would say wrapping them all in another parentheses is unnecessary and would solve a bit different problem.

Comment: yes, that will do the trick, but not in the shortest form, I guess I should have been more precise - how can I do so in a, lets call it "canonical form", like in my example?

Comment: @spbnick haha indeed `/^(abcd|abxy|abz)$/` :p

Comment: @user1088045 The solution is right before you, don't try to make it compacter. 1) To do it you have to create a complex regex builder 2) it will make your regex unreadable 3) unmaintainable

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I've amended my answer to remove parentheses addition, as they don't seem to be necessary. Regarding, your second variant, moving ^ and $ outside would be a more complicated task and wouldn't work if some of the patterns don't have them. What I meant in my original reply is adding parentheses around all of the patterns isn't necessary for matching, but adds capture as a side effect, which wasn't requested by OP. Such addition is actually an operation separate from combining the patterns.